# Java, Mockito: Field mocked via @InjectMocks does not notice new value written into the real variable

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have not much experience with Mockito - and I found some behaviour which I can not explain: I have a simple class let's say like this

```
 public class Testee {

  protected MyParam myParam;

  public void myMethod(){
    myParam = new MyParam();
    myParam.someField = "a new value";
  }
```

The type of the variable `myParam` in this class is a class with, let's say, only one pubic field:

```
public class MyParam {

  public String someField;
}
```

Now I want to write a test for the `Testee` class and I do it like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestTestee {

  @InjectMocks
  Testee testee = new Testee();

  @Mock
  MyParam myParam;

  @Test
  public void testMyMethod(){
    myParam.someField = "old value";
    testee.myMethod();
    assertEquals("a new value", myParam.someField);
  }
}
```

But this test fails! The resulting message is:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected: a new value
Actual: old value
```

So, the mock is actually injected correctly, but it does not seem to notice, that the method in the real class writes a new value into the mocked variable (`myParam = new MyParam();`). The value of the mock remains the same - and the test fails. This is a bit confusing to me, especially regarding, that if I simply remove the line `myParam = new MyParam();`, then the test succeeds!

So, the mock is not able to notice a new object being written into the mocked variable, but it does notice changes made to the object - do I understand it correctly? And what would be the proper way to test the value written into `myParam` by `myMethod()` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because on the line in `Testee` where `myParam = new MyParam()`, the reference to the class member `Testee testee` is reassigned to `new MyParam()`. The mock object in the test has not been reassigned and still points to the original value.

To resolve this, you could add setter `setSomeField(String someField)` to `MyParam` and instead of reassigning the value, in `Testee`, call `myParam.setSomeField("a new value")`.

> So, the mock is not able to notice a new object being written into the
>   mocked variable, but it does notice changes made to the object - do I
>   understand it correctly?

It's all about which object in memory that the reference is pointed to. In the test, we create a mock and the mocking framework sets the class member to the object reference of the mock.

We then reassign the class member but our unit test checks the mock. The mock's object reference has not been changed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not really need a mock here as you want to pass an object with a certain state. You might reconsider and simply use a setter.

If you really have to and possibly need to mock some of the public methods of that class then try to use a spy instead of a mock:

```
@Spy
MyParam myParam;
```

Now by default, all the real implementation will be called and you need to mock explicitly certain methods that you want to be stubbed.